# How to use Django Social Auth to connect with Instagram?

Tags: django, authentication, instagram, django-socialauth

How to setup Django to authenticate with Instagram by default?
Tried django-socialauth, but no results.
Which way is the best?

Answer (score 1):

Check this out:
I've found solution from sample_app.py in python-instagram :) And sync with django auth

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect, HttpResponse
from django.contrib.auth import login, logout
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.shortcuts import render
from instagram import client
from app.models import UserProfile

unauthenticated_api = client.InstagramAPI(**settings.INSTAGRAM_CONFIG)

@login_required
def index(request):
    return render(request, 'app/index.html', {})

def on_login(request):
    try:
    url = unauthenticated_api.get_authorize_url(scope=["likes","comments"])
    return render(request, 'app/login.html', {'url': url})
    except Exception as e:
    print(e)

def on_callback(request):
    code = request.GET.get("code")
    if not code:
    return "Missing code"
    try:
    access_token, user_info = unauthenticated_api.exchange_code_for_access_token(code)
    if not access_token:
        return "Could not get access token"
    api = client.InstagramAPI(access_token=access_token, client_secret=settings.INSTAGRAM_CONFIG['client_secret'])
    request.session['access_token'] = access_token
    print "%s" % access_token
    except Exception as e:
    print(e)

    print "%s" % user_info
    print "%s" % user_info['username']
    user, created = User.objects.get_or_create(username=user_info['username'])
    user.backend = 'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend'

    if user:
    if user.is_active:
        login(request, user)
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/app/')
    else:
        return HttpResponse("Your account is disabled.")
    else:
    return HttpResponse("No login.")

@login_required
def on_logout(request):
    logout(request)

    return HttpResponseRedirect('/app/')
```

Answer (score 0):

It's simple first redirect your users to this url

```
BASE_URL = "https://api.instagram.com/oauth/authorize/?"
REDIRECT_URI = "http://127.0.0.1:5000/grant-access"
url = BASE_URL + "client_id={}&redirect_uri={}&response_type=code".format(CLIENT_ID, REDIRECT_URI)
return HttpResponseRedirect(url)
```

Then

```
REQUEST_ACCESS = "https://api.instagram.com/oauth/access_token/?"
def grant_access(request):
    code = request.GET.get('code')
    payload = {'client_id': CLIENT_ID, 'client_secret':CLIENT_SECRET, 'grant_type':'authorization_code','redirect_uri': REDIRECT_URI, 'code': code}
    resp = requests.post(REQUEST_ACCESS, data= payload)
    response = json.loads(resp.text)
```

Now you will have the access-token save that one into db for later use and log in